# Meteor DDP SSL/Apache Proxy Connection

Tags: apache, ssl, meteor, proxy, ddp

I have Debian host that runs my Meteor application on NodeJS that listens: 127.0.0.1:3999
I also have a domain register https://example.com that welcomed with Apache and proxied to my Meteor application.

I have problem with DDP Connection.
my connection link is `ws://example.com/websocket`

I set the ProxyPass settings as following:

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName example.com
      ServerAlias www.example.com

      SSLEngine on
      SSLProxyEngine On
      ProxyRequests Off

      SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www.example.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/www.example.key
      SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem

      ProxyPass /websocket ws://localhost:3999/websocket
      ProxyPassReverse /websocket ws://localhost:3999/websocket

      ProxyPassMatch ^/sockjs/(.*)/websocket ws://localhost:3999/sockjs/$1/websocket
      ProxyPass / http://localhost:3999/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3999/

      BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
           nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
           downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
      # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
      BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
 </VirtualHost>
```

And

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName example.com
      ServerAlias www.example.com
      ProxyRequests off


       RewriteEngine on
       ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$

       # This allows DDP clients like ObjectiveDDP and Meteor-Unity to connect
       RewriteRule ^/websocket wss://%{HTTP_HOST}/websocket [NC,R,L]

       # This allows the meteor webapp to connect
       RewriteRule ^/sockjs/(.*)/websocket wss://%{HTTP_HOST}/sockjs/$1/websocket [NC,R,L]
       RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is not to use debian, instead use ubuntu, so Apache 2.6 would be available. mod_proxy_wstunnel has solved the problem with v2.6.